# Neural network to recognise handwritten digits: Dealing with multiple outputs

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network

I'm trying to write my own neural network as a learning exercise. Specifically, I'm trying to create a neural network to recognise handwritten digits. I'm using sklearn's [digits dataset](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/datasets/plot_digits_last_image.html), but have written the neural network myself.

Simple tests are successful, i.e. OR gates or AND gates, so I am confident that back-propagation has been implemented successfully, but I'm finding that **after training, the network still works very poorly when working with a 8x8 pixel image of a handwritten digits.** I currently have 64 inputs (8x8 image) and 10 outputs (one for each digit), with 2 hidden layers each of size 4. I suspect it's the multiple outputs that are causing problems, as often the network will reach activations of [0.1, 0.1, 0.1...] (i.e. the average of 0.0 * 9 + 1.0 * 1) .

Possible thoughts:

1) Are multiple outputs causing problems?

2) Is a better error function needed?

3) Do I just need to train the system for much longer on a smaller learning rate?

[Image showing the error over iterations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2bSB.png)

[Image showing the prediction of a 1 (i.e. output should be ~[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]) after training](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuFGo.png)

Has anyone faced a similar problem to this? Or can advise as to where I might be going wrong? Thanks for being patient if this has been asked before and I didn't find it! Code below:

**EDIT:** Both charlesreid1 and jdehesa were right, it was the fact that my network architecture was too simple to handle this task. More specifically, I had 2 layers of 4 neurons each trying to handle 64 inputs. Changing my hidden layers to 3 layers of 100 neurons each allowed me to reach a 90% accuracy score (Assuming an output of > 0.7 is considered a positive result).

```
    # Import our dependencies

    import numpy as np
    from sklearn import datasets

    class Neural_Network():

        #Initalising function
        def __init__(self, input_size, output_size, niteration = 100000):

            np.random.seed(1)

            self.niteration = niteration
            self.layer_sizes = np.array([input_size, output_size])
            self.weights = list()
            self.error = np.array([])

            # initialise random weights
            self._recreate_weights()


        def _recreate_weights(self):
            # Recreate the weights after adding a hidden layer
            self.weights = list()

            for i in np.arange(len(self.layer_sizes) - 1):

                weights = np.random.rand(self.layer_sizes[i], self.layer_sizes[i+1]) * 2 - 1
                self.weights.append(weights)
            self.momentum = [i * 0 for i in self.weights]


        def add_hidden_layer(self,size):
            # Add a new hidden layer to our neural network
            self.layer_sizes = np.insert(self.layer_sizes, -1, size)
            self._recreate_weights()



        def _sigmoid(self, x, deriv=False):

            if deriv:
                return self._sigmoid(x, deriv=False)*(1-self._sigmoid(x, deriv=False))
            else:
                return 1.0/(1+np.exp(-x))



        def predict(self, input_single, deriv=False, layer_output = False):

            data_current_layer = input_single
            output_list = list()
            output_list.append(np.array([data_current_layer]))
            for i in np.arange(len(self.layer_sizes) - 1):
                data_current_layer = self._sigmoid(np.dot(data_current_layer, self.weights[i]), deriv)
                output_list.append(np.array([data_current_layer]))

            return(output_list)



        def train2(self, input_training_data, input_training_labels):

            for iterations in np.arange(self.niteration):
                # Loop over all training sets niteration times

                updates = [i * 0 for i in network.weights] # Used for storing the update to the weights
                mean_error = np.array([]) # used for calculating the mean error

                for i in np.arange(len(input_training_data)): # For each training example

                    activations = list() # Store all my activations in a list
                    activations.append(np.array([input_training_data[i]]))

                    for j in np.arange(len(self.layer_sizes) - 1):
                        # Calculate all the activations for every layer

                        z = np.dot(activations[-1], self.weights[j])
                        a = self._sigmoid(z, deriv = False)
                        activations.append(a)

                    error = list()
                    error.append(a[-1] - np.array([input_training_labels[i]]))

                    for j in np.arange(len(self.layer_sizes) - 2):
                        # Calculate the error term for each layer

                        j2 = (-1 * j) - 1
                        j3 = j2 - 1
                        d = np.dot(error[j], self.weights[j2].T) * activations[j3] * (1 - activations[j3])
                        error.append(d)

                    for j in np.arange(len(self.layer_sizes) - 1):
                        # calculate the gradient for the error with respect to the weights

                        j2 = (-1 * j) - 1
                        updates[j] += np.dot(activations[j].T, error[j2])


                    mean_error = np.append(mean_error, np.sum(np.abs(error[0])))

                updates = [0.001*i/len(input_training_data) for i in updates] # Add in a learning rate
                self.error = np.append(self.error,np.mean(mean_error))

                for i in np.arange(len(self.weights)):
                    # update using a momentum term
                    self.momentum[i] -= updates[i]
                    self.weights[i]  += self.momentum[i]
                    self.momentum[i] *= 0.9

                if np.mod(iterations, 1000) == 0:
                    # Visually keep track of the error
                    print(iterations, self.error[-1])


    # Main Loop


    # Read in the dataset and divide into a training and test set
    data = datasets.load_digits()
    images = data.images
    labels = data.target
    targets = data.target_names

    training_images = images[:int(len(labels*0.8))]
    training_labels = labels[:int(len(labels*0.8))]

    training_images = images[:10]
    training_labels = labels[:10]

    test_images = images[int(len(labels*0.8)):]
    test_labels = labels[int(len(labels*0.8)):]

    # Flatten the training and test images using ravel. CAN PROBABLY DO THIS BEFORE DIVIDING THEM UP.
    training_images_list = list()
    for i in training_images:
        training_images_list.append(np.ravel(i))

    test_images_list = list()
    for i in test_images:
        test_images_list.append(np.ravel(i))


    # Change the training and test labels into a more usable format.

    training_labels_temp=np.zeros([np.size(training_labels), 10])
    for i in np.arange(np.size(training_labels)):
        training_labels_temp[i, training_labels[i]] = 1
    training_labels = training_labels_temp

    test_labels_temp=np.zeros([np.size(test_labels), 10])
    for i in np.arange(np.size(test_labels)):
        test_labels_temp[i, test_labels[i]] = 1
    test_labels = test_labels_temp


    # Build a 3 layered neural network, input - hidden - output

    if True:
        network = Neural_Network(input_size=64, output_size=10)

        network.add_hidden_layer(size=4)
        network.add_hidden_layer(size=4)
        network.add_hidden_layer(size=4)



        # Train the network on our training set
        #print(network.weights)
        network.train2(input_training_data = training_images_list, input_training_labels = training_labels)
        #print(network.weights)

        # Calculate the error on our test set

        #network.calculate_error(test_set = test_images, test_labels = test_labels)
```

Comment: Most likely, your network is too small. According to your first image, the training seems to be working, but in your second image the net can't decide whether it is a 1, a 2 or a 6 - which is more or less understandable. Try with something much bigger, something like three 100-unit layers, and see if (after training for a while, since it will take longer) you see any difference.

Comment: The other factor (maybe both are important) is the learning rate. The loss curve is smooth, so it's definitely not excessively high, but it could be too low... but the loss values that you are getting are already rather small and stable, so I don't think you are going to get much further with you current model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem definitely lies with your network architecture - specifically, the first hidden layer. You're feeding the 8x8 input to a hidden layer with 4 neurons. First, there aren't enough neurons, the information contained in the 64 pixels is being washed out by being passed through only four neurons. The other issue (which may go away with enough neurons) is that each neuron is fully connected to the inputs, due to your `predict()` function's use of the dot product.

The task of recognizing handwritten digits is inherently tied to spatial configuration of pixels, so your network should take advantage of that knowledge. You should feed different parts of the input image to different neurons in the first layer. This provides the opportunity for these neurons to amplify stronger or dampen weaker signals based on the arrangement of pixels in the image (e.g., if you see a large signal in the corners, it's unlikely to be a 1, if you see a large signal right in the center, it's unlikely to be a 0, etc.).

Generalizing this idea is what [convolutional neural networks](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/tutorial/supervised/ConvolutionalNeuralNetwork/) are all about - and why they work so well for image recognition tasks. There's another nice writeup by O'Reilly Publishers called [Not Another MNIST Tutorial](https://www.oreilly.com/learning/not-another-mnist-tutorial-with-tensorflow) that is, indeed, not another tutorial, but shows some really helpful visualizations to understanding what's going on.

The long and short of it is this: AND/OR is a very simple task, but you've jumped to a very complex task - and your neural network architecture should have the architecture needed to make a corresponding jump in complexity. Convolutional neural networks generally follow an architectural pattern:

- Divide up parts of the image, distributing different parts to different neurons (convolution layer)
- Re-combine information from different parts of the image (pooling layer)
- Filter out weak signals (dropout layer)
- Convert spatial information to a vector signal (flatten layer)
- Create another layer of neurons fully connected to the neurons of the prior layer (dense layer)

Larger CNNs for more complex tasks will combine these layers into larger, nested architectures and sub-networks. Knowing what combinations of layers to use is something of an art and can take a lot of experimentation (hence the popularity of GPUs - makes it much faster to iterate and experiment). But for grayscale handwritten digits, you should see a big improvement just by taking advantage of information you already know about the task at hand - viz., that it should take advantage of spatial structure.

Comment: This is the correct answer. See the edit on my original question for more information, but in short more neurons enabled extra complexity in my network, and it was able to identify handwritten digits to a 90% accuracy. Thanks Charles!